# Combine already published .Net Core Web API files and public selenium/standalone-chrome container into a single Docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, selenium-webdriver, asp.net-web-api, dockerfile

**Dotnet publish** was run first.

```
dotnet publish WebApi.csproj -c Release -o out_linux -r linux-x64
```

By **selenium/standalone-chrome** we mean the image from here

```
https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome
```

If put **Dockerfile** below into **out_linux** directory how to achieve merging asp.net + selenium into a single container. I tried different combinations but was unable to achieve that. I don't want **dotnet publish** to be included into Dockerfile due to existing infrastructure.
For current variant container looks like **dotnet** either lost or cannot be found. If change FROM sequence and put Selenium first by the size of container is quite clear that merging didn't happen and second FROM wipes out previous stage.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim as base 
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./

FROM selenium/standalone-chrome
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=base /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.WebApi.dll"]
```

Message on "docker run"
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "dotnet": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with using **selenium/standalone-chrome** as a separate container and **RemoteWebDriver** instead of **ChromeDriver** for scraping. The attempt to aggregate into a single container seems to be pointless and doesn't have any value.